# Why is there a traceback error while using continue in a "While True" loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a simple program to convert metric units to imperial unit(not included because it works fine) But i can't figure out why the "continue" makes a traceback error when it should just restart the loop?

```
import sys
import time

def converter():
    while True:
        cont_1 = input('Do you want to do another calculation? (Yes, No) ')                       
        if cont_1 == 'no' or 'No':
            break
        elif cont_1 == 'yes' or 'Yes':
            continue
    return
converter()

sys.exit()
```

I expect the program to restart when i type in 'yes' or 'Yes'. When in reality i get a traceback error.

Comment: `sys.exit()` is useless, since the program should terminate anyway when it reaches the end.

Comment: This `cont_1 == 'no' or 'No'` (or this `cont_1 == 'yes' or 'Yes'`) is not what you expect it to be, it's always `True` when used in an `if` statement.

Comment: always show full `Traceback` in question

Comment: I run it and I get Traceback created by `sys.exit()` but it is normal

Comment: You should use `if cont_1 in ('no', 'No')` or `if cont_1.lower() == 'no'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Traceback` is created by `sys.exit()` but it can be normal when you run in some IDE.

But you don't need `sys.exit()`. If you remove it then you will  have no `Traceback`

---

But there is other problem - your `if` doesn't work as you expect and it exits `while` loop and then it execute `sys.exit()`

Line

```
   if cont_1 == 'no' or 'No':
```

means

```
  if (cont_1 == 'no') or 'No':
```

and this awlays gives `True` and it exits `while` loop.

You need

```
  if cont_1 == 'no' or cont_1 == 'No':
```

or

```
  if cont_1 in ('no', 'No'):
```

or use `string.lower()`

```
  if cont_1.lower() == 'no':
```

Last version will work also with `NO`, and `nO`

---

you can use

```
  elif cont_1 == 'yes' or 'Yes':
     continue
```

which has the same problem but after `continue` is no code in `while` so you don't need it

So you need only

```
def converter():
    while True:
        cont_1 = input('Do you want to do another calculation? (Yes, No) ')                       
        if cont_1.lower() == 'no':
            break
    return

converter()
```

or put `return` in places of `break`

```
def converter():
    while True:
        cont_1 = input('Do you want to do another calculation? (Yes, No) ')                       
        if cont_1.lower() == 'no':
            return

converter()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not understanding the way Python if statements work, now it will always be false.

Either write them like this:

```
if cont_1 == 'no' or cont_1 == 'No':
```

Or perhaps easier in this case:

```
if cont_1.lower() == 'no':
```

Answer (score 1):

actually you are using a completely logically wrong way to run this code
so your code should be like this:

```
import sys
def converter():
    cont_1 = input('Do you want to do another calculation? (Yes/ No) ')                
    if cont_1 == 'no' or cont_1 == 'No':
        sys.exit()
    if cont_1 == 'yes' or cont_1 == 'Yes':
        pass
while True:
    converter()
```